# Replace Object inside an Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

I have one array having multiple objects (say 3 Objects), each having 3 "Key-Value" pairs.

`$PredefinedResult` is something like this :

```
[
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":0,
        "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
        "RecordCount":0
    },
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":0,
        "EffectiveStatus":"def",
        "RecordCount":0
    },
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":0,
        "EffectiveStatus":"ghi",
        "RecordCount":0
    }
]
```

I have another array of objects named `$MainResult` with values like :

```
[
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":1,
        "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
        "RecordCount":7
    },
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":6,
        "EffectiveStatus":"def",
        "RecordCount":91
    }
]
```

**Expected Result :**

I want to replace the similar objects inside `$PredefinedResult` with the objects from `$MainResult` and want result like this :

```
[
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":1,
        "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
        "RecordCount":7
    },
    {
        "EffectiveStatusId":6,
        "EffectiveStatus":"def",
        "RecordCount":91
    },
    {
         "EffectiveStatusId":0,
         "EffectiveStatus":"ghi",
         "RecordCount":0
    }
]
```

**What I tried :**

I tried with this code but it's not giving me the desired result.

```
$FinalResult = array_replace($PredefineResult,$MainResult);
```

Can anyone help me on how to get the Expected Result as mentioned above ?

Comment: That's JSON. Are you actually decoding it before?

Comment: @AmalMurali : No, I have just formatted it so that everyone can see the result what i want. Actually it's an Array of Objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "built-in" function for this.  You're gonna have to loop and compare each manually.  `array_map` seems like an OK choice here:

```
$PredefinedResult = array_map(function($a) use($MainResult){
    foreach($MainResult as $data){
        if($a->EffectiveStatus === $data->EffectiveStatus){
            return $data;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}, $PredefinedResult);
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OHBQK8

Comment: Demo no longer accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the array and manual compare the values as follows.

```
$res = array();
foreach ($PredefineResult as $result){
    foreach ($MainResult as $mresult){
        if(($result->EffectiveStatus == $mresult->EffectiveStatus) && $mresult->RecordCount!=0){
            $res[] = $mresult;
        }else $res[] = $result;
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to be work. Can you explain me how `array_unique()` will select only object with `RecordCount != 0` ? See the result I want is that Object with `RecordCount == 0` should be replaced with `RecordCount != 0`.

Comment: Seems your key is `EffectiveStatus` for each array. Then you have to go with foreach(); Let me update my answer accordingly.